# Updating an object in state in a FunctionalComponent in Preact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

In useEffect, a fetch call is made to the backend `app.js` to get some data, which is returned as an object `laStateObj`.

```
useEffect(() => {
   fetchCall<{ laStateObj }>('/fetchData').then((data) => {
      const ddata = JSON.parse(data);
      setLaStateObj({
         email: ddata.email,
         approved: ddata.approved
      });
   });
}, []);
```

I created a setter that updates that state value:

```
const [laStateObj, setLaStateObj] = setState({email: undefined, approved: undefined});
```

When a radio button value is changed, I wish to switch the state of the boolean value `approved`:

```
<Checkbox checked={laStateObj.approved} onChange={(prev.approved) => !prev.approved} />
```

That didn't work, so I added a handler:

```
<Checkbox checked={laStateObj.approved} onChange={handleApproved} />

const handleApproved = () => {
   const prevApproved = laStateObj.approved;
   setLaStateObj = {...laStateObj, approved: !prevApproved};
};
```

I'm pretty sure that's wrong (my linter says it is...) - so how should this be written?

*Note that this is Preact, not React, so syntax can be a bit different.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setLaStateObj` is a function and is `const` so you can't do something like `setLaStateObj = {...laStateObj, approved: !prevApproved};`.

If you want to toggle the approved state I believe it should be

```
setLaStateObj(state => ({
  ...state,
  approved: !state.approved
}))
```

Spread the previous state in and update the `approved` property.

```
const handleApproved = () => {
  setLaStateObj(state => ({
    ...state,
    approved: !state.approved
  }))
};

...

<Checkbox checked={laStateObj.approved} onChange={handleApproved} />
```